How to display great_tables in databricks
I love the control that the great_tables package offers, but in databricks the table results are outputted in a really vanilla fashion. Is there anyway to display great_tables results in their full splendor within databricks?
from great_tables import GT
GT(pl_ci)



Great Tables expects Pandas dataframe. If you want to use it, GT(df.toPandas()) can be used.
By converting to Pandas, you are bringing all the data to driver node which may not be effective in large datasets.

display(spark_dataframe) has more features and works faster. Please try that.
